# How to convert a list of digits to a string in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, conversion

I want to convert a list of digits to a string, for example from `{1,2,3,4,5}`, I want to get the string 12345.

The following will work as long as the list does not begin with 0's:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // FromDigits // ToString    
Out[10]:= 12345
```

However if the list begins with 0's, as in

```
{0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4} // FromDigits // ToString
Out[11]:= 1234
```

this method chops off the 0's in the front.

I could write a program that tests to see if the list begins with a string of 0's and then append that many zeros to the chopped off output, but I'd like a less procedural way of getting the string. Is this possible?

Note: the lists I want to convert are going to come from some prior computation, so unlike the above examples, I won't know their contents unless I explicitely examine them.

Comment: Try `StringRiffle[{0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, ""]` introduced in version 10.1

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
StringRiffle[{0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, ""]
"001234"
```

Introduced in version 10.1 or in postfix as follows:

```
{0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4} // StringRiffle[#, ""] &
```

Answer (score 10):

While `StringRiffle` is nice and concise, but it has -- similar to many of the `String`-related tools in Mathematica -- severe performance issues. For example, the combination of `IntegerString` and `StringJoin` is ten times faster. Even roman465's somewhat creative solution to first convert the whole expression to a string and to remove the undesired parts afterwards is five times faster. *If you can be be sure that only digits from `0` to `9` appear in the list*, you can also use `FromCharacterCode` which is faster by almost two further orders of magnitude.

```
a = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 100000];

s1 = StringRiffle[a, ""]; // RepeatedTiming // First
s2 = a // ToString // StringDelete[#, {"{", ", ", "}"}] &; // RepeatedTiming // First
s3 = StringJoin[IntegerString[a]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
s4 = FromCharacterCode[a + 48]; // RepeatedTiming // First
s1 == s2 == s3 == s4
```

> 0.311
>
> 0.0649
>
> 0.036
>
> 0.000534
>
> True

Answer (score 5):

It might be more convenient to convert your list to a string first, then remove unnecessary symbols.

```
{0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4} // ToString // StringDelete[#, {"{", ", ", "}"}] &
```

> "001234"

Answer (score 5):

It can also be done in this way

```
StringJoin[ToString /@ {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

Comment: This feels like the most readable and syntactically correct to me.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Using the three-argument form of `IntegerString`:

```
IntegerString[FromDigits @ #, 10, Length @ #] & @ {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

> "00001234"

Answer (score 0):

Some additional alternatives:

```
TextString[Row@#] &@{0, 0, 1, 3}
```

> ```
> "0013"
> ```

```
TextString[#, ListFormat -> {"", "", ""}] &@{0, 0, 1, 3}
```

> ```
> "0013"
> ```

```
StringDrop[ToString@FromDigits[Prepend[#, 1]], 1] &@{0, 0, 1, 3}
```

> ```
> "0013"
> ```